# How to get the request url from HttpServletRequest

Tags: http, url, servlets, uri

Say i make a get request like this:

```
GET http://cotnet.diggstatic.com:6000/js/loader/443/JS_Libraries,jquery|Class|analytics|lightbox|label|jquery-dom|jquery-cookie?q=hello#frag HTTP/1.0
Host: cotnet.diggstatic.com:6000
```

My servlet takes request like this:
HttpServletRequest req;

When i debug my server and execute, i get the following:

```
req.getRequestURL().toString() = "http://cotnet.diggstatic.com:6000/js/loader/443/JS_Libraries,jquery%7cClass%7canalytics%7clightbox%7clabel%7cjquery-dom%7cjquery-cookie"
req.getRequestURI() = "/js/loader/443/JS_Libraries,jquery%7cClass%7canalytics%7clightbox%7clabel%7cjquery-dom%7cjquery-cookie"
req.getQueryString() = "q=hello"
```

How does one get the fragment information ?
Also, when i debug the request, i see a uri_ field of type java.net.URI which has the fragment information. This is exactly what i want. How can i get that ?

Answer (score 11):

"The fragment identifier functions differently than the rest of the URI: namely, its processing is exclusively client-side with no participation from the server." [Wikipedia about the Frament Identifiert](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier)

For further reference see the [RFC 2394 Section 4.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2396)