# How to detect Fragment identifiers in Url Mappings?

Tags: grails, groovy, fragment-identifier, url-mapping, urlmappings.groovy

In a [Grails](http://www.grails.org/) project I'm trying to map a Url based on whether or not a **[Fragment Identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier)** is present in the Url.  The Fragment Identifiers are important because a Flash library [SWFAddress](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SWFAddress) uses them to communicate to a Flash application present in the web page.

I simply need to determine whether a fragment is present or not in the Request url.

Should I look into [HttpServletRequest](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html) to do this?

**What's the best way in Grails to route a url based on whether a Fragment Identifier is present in a Url?**

[I asked [this same question at the Grails forum](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/How-to-detect-Fragment-identifiers-in-Url-Mappings-tt3479887.html).]

Comment: This Stack Overflow question is relevant: [How to get the request url from HttpServletRequest?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2860718/how-to-get-the-request-url-from-httpservletrequest) and the Wikipedia article on the [Fragment Identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier). In short - the fragment identifier is only dealt with client-side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A fragment identifier is not part of a URL, it is merely used in conjunction with a URL. It is of value only to the client.

A compliant server will ignore any fragment identifier sent by a client.

You can't design your url mappings based on fragment identifiers, the URL will not contain a fragment identifier by the time it reaches your app.