# How to get full URL which contains # from HttpServletRequest

Tags: java, servlets

In my sample application i am displaying some records, based on # am scrolling down to a particular topic. But to edit that message user has to logon. But while constructing destination url in signin pagebased on request object of servlet am not getting the # in url.

URL looks like www.mydomain:8080/SMP/Account/display/topic#M7

```
   public static String getFullURL(HttpServletRequest request) {
    StringBuffer requestURL = request.getRequestURL();//**http://xyz:8080/SMP/Account/display/topic**
    String queryString = request.getQueryString();
  .....
   }
```

FYI i have a restriction on setting referer.
Is there any other-way to get full url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot get the url fragment identifier from the `HttpServletRequest` as its not actually passed along to the server, it is for the client only.

A quick Google for `HttpServletRequest fragment identifier` should confirm that, including:

[How to get the URL fragment identifier from HttpServletRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13503213/how-to-get-the-url-fragment-identifier-from-httpservletrequest)

[How to detect Fragment identifiers in Url Mappings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5811898/how-to-detect-fragment-identifiers-in-url-mappings)

etc