# Retrieve the URL

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

I have a URL which gets formed like below:
http://localhost:8080/app/angular/users/#/update/745

When i try to get the URL using `request.getRequestURL()`I get the URL till http://localhost:8080/app/angular/users. I tried different methods from `HTTPServletRequest` but none worked.

Can someone please help on this ? I need to understand how can i get full URL, and what is with #.

Comment: You can't. Hash parameter don't get sent to the server.

Answer (score 0):

The `#` is a fragment identifier. You can't get the data after it, it doesn't get sent to the server.

[How to get full URL which contains # from HttpServletRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27332811/how-to-get-full-url-which-contains-from-httpservletrequest)

To solve this, just don't use the `#` as a method to pass parameters. Stick with the request parameters such as `http://localhost:8080/app/angular/users/update?id=745` and have Spring read in a GET method on the Controller, or use it as a path variable such as `http://localhost:8080/app/angular/users/update/745`, something you can also retrieve from Spring controllers.

Answer (score 0):

getPathInfo() gives the extra path information after the URI, used to access your Servlet, where as getRequestURI() gives the complete URI.

I would have thought they would be different, given a Servlet must be configured with its own URI pattern in the first place; I don't think I've ever served a Servlet from root (/).

For example if Servlet 'Foo' is mapped to URI '/foo' then I would have thought the URI:

/foo/path/to/resource
Would result in:

RequestURI = /foo/path/to/resource
and

PathInfo = /path/to/resource