# How to read the url from request

Tags: java, spring

I want to read a request url using spring ,i have method like below and the client request url is like http://localhost:8080/api/getName ,i want to read (/api/getName from this url)

```
@Controller
public class TestController  {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<String> getDetails(
            final HttpServletRequest request,
            final HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

        }
```

Comment: Why? Are you going to put your own dispatch mechanism on top of the one already in Spring?

Answer (score 1):

It's a method in `HttpServletRequest`: `request.getRequestURL()` gives you the URL.

See this answer for some more details: [How to get the request url from HttpServletRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2860718/how-to-get-the-request-url-from-httpservletrequest)

To further analyse the URL, use it's methods: [Parsing a URL](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/urlInfo.html)

Comment: is there any way just to read '/api/getName' from the entire url that is http://localhost:8080/api/getName ?

Comment: Use `getPath()` on the URL: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/urlInfo.html

Comment: @user1195292: the method getRequestURI() returns exactly what you are asking for. See API Doc linked in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

`req.getContextPath();`

Should get you the context path you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to browse the api javadocs

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html

Answer (score 0):

> i want to read (/api/getName from this url)

For this you can use the HttpServletRequest method [getRequestURI()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRequestURI%28%29). It will return the request URL, without the protocol/server/port part, and without the query String (the parameters).