# How to get value from address after #?

Tags: java, jsp, url

I want to get value after `#` sign from URL address in jsp

```
http://www.example.com/testsite/sative.do?runninginformation=11-1970-1#11197011201240649438FT
```

How can I get it using query string?

Comment: yes @RohitJain complete string after# sign using query string or some other way, actually i want to highlight table row after getting that string in jsp

Comment: @Danish.. Well, you have already got the answer. Use the first answer.

Comment: @RohitJain when i get the page url using: String completeUrl = request.getRequestURL().toString() + "" + request.getQueryString();, i never get the after # value in completeUrl String

Comment: @RohitJain did u get my point

Comment: [This link](http://www.coderanch.com/t/360089/Servlets/java/text-request) and [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2860718/how-to-get-the-request-url-from-httpservletrequest) may interest you.

Comment: In all, the fragment part is something that is for client side only. Server side has nothing to do with it. So, you can't get it from `HttpRequest` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about:

```
"http://www.example.com/testsite/sative.do?runninginformation=11-1970-1#11197011201240649438FT".replaceAll(".*#","");
```

this will return `11197011201240649438FT`

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
String url = "http://www.example.com/testsite/sative.do?runninginformation=11-1970-1#11197011201240649438FT";
String f = new URI(url).getFragment();
System.out.println(f);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `split`, which will split the value into array.

```
String x = "hello#World";
String[] y = x.split("#");
System.out.print(y[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't. The value after the pound-sign (#) is never sent to the server.

You will need to do some javascript processing. Basically add an onclick-handler for each link, parse the URL of the link and extract the hash-portion and add it as a regular parameter instead.